# How to retrieve a function key from an ADO pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to retrieve the function key through an ADO file and I am able to retrieve the function key with the following code:

```
az functionapp function keys list -g my_subscription -n my_function_app --function-name my function
```

How can I place this code to work in a yml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to place this command into my yml file with the following lines of code:

```
        - task: AzureCLI@1
        displayName: 'Retrieve Function Keys'
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'XXXX'
          scriptType: 'ps'
          scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
          inlineScript: |
            az functionapp function keys list -g my_subscription -n my_function_app --function-name my_function
```